# Where is \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductExtensionInterface?

Tags: product, api, interface

In Magento Product class (\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product)
there is the function

```
public function setExtensionAttributes(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductExtensionInterface $extensionAttributes)
```

However, if I look at Magento codebase (e.g. https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Api/Data) there is no \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductExtensionInterface.

How come? There is probably something that I have not understood fully, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, this is an autogenerated class/interface and can be found at generated-folder.